# $\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z[x]/I$ and $(\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z[x]/I)/J$ quotients rings. Prime elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm, quotient-set

I need some help with this exersise because it mixes quotients rings, concruences, ideals, polynomials and it mess me up. I don't even know how to start. **Any help will be appreciated.**

> Let $R=\Bbb Z / 3 \Bbb Z$ and $I$ the ideal generated by $p(x)=x^2+[2]_3x+[1]_3$ in $R[x]$.
>
> (a) Is $R[x]/I$ integral domain? If so, **prove** it.
>
> (b) Is $([2]_3x+[1]_3)+I$ a unit in $R[x]/I$? If so, find the inverse of $([2]_3x+[1]_3)+I$ **using the Euclidean Algorithm**.
>
> (c) Let $S:=R[x]/I$. **Calculate** $S/((x+[1]_3)+I)$ and **say** whether $(x+[1]_3)+I$ is prime or not in $S.$

---

What I've done so far:

(a) As $p(x)=(x+[1]_3)^2$ is not prime and R[x] is a PID then the ideal generated by p(x) is not prime so that $R[x]/I$ is not an integral domain. *(Thanks for the hints in the comments.)*

(b) $gcd(x^2+[2]_3x+[1]_3, \; [2]_3x+[1]_3)=1$ so I get $x^2+[2]_3x+[1]_3=([2]_3x)([2]_3x+[1]_3)$. Thus, $$0+I=(([2]_3x)([2]_3x+[1]_3)+1)+I,$$ and $$1+I=(([2]_3x)([2]_3x+[1]_3))+I=(([2]_3x)+I)\cdot (([2]_3x+[1]_3)+I),$$ so the multiplicative inverse of $([2]_3x+[1]_3)+I$ is $[2]_3x+I$. $\color{red}{Am\; I \; wrong?}$

(c) I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Note:   $p(x)=(x+[1]_3)^2$

Comment: Building off of what @J.W.Tanner said, there is a handy result that says $R[x]/I$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal. What can you say about $I$ being a prime ideal, knowing that $p(x)$ is reducible?

Comment: As $p(x)$ is not prime and $R[x]$ is a PID then the ideal generated by $p(x)$ is not prime so that $R[x]I$ is not  an integral domain? @Sunyata

Comment: Yes. This is one of the nifty things that PIDs give you.

Comment: Ok, so I think I'm done with (a) and probably with (b) too. But what about (c), any hint? Could you please tell me if (b) is correct?